# Use AppleScript to change System Preferences without being visible?

Tags: macos, applescript

I would like to change settings in System Preferences without the user seeing things happen.
If I have a script that starts like:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
```

the System Preference window will be shown to the user.
I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in the background somehow, or at least keep the window minimized.

(Example script can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160095/how-to-use-applescript-to-change-preference-pane-slider-value).)

Comment: What setting do you want to change?

Comment: Today, brightness settings, but I'd like a general solution for tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do what you want with with the command line app [defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html), there are some other command line apps that can manipulate other system stuff also like, [pmset](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

Some things can be set using scripting additions also, for example the systems volumn can be set using the standard additions, you also you may be able to find other scripting additions to add more stuff.

Comment: Pretty cool! Not sure it will help me this time, but useful for future issues!

Answer (score 3):

You can just remove the activate command. System Events can perform actions in hidden windows.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

If you open menus, they will be visible though.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "TTS" of pane "com.apple.preference.speech"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        click
        if value is "Alex" then
            click menu item "Kathy" of menu 1
        else
            click menu item "Alex" of menu 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

The brightness of displays can also be changed with [brightness.c](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/).